# Logistic regression prediction validation

Tags: r, regression, logistic

I am try to evaluate a logistic regression with new data using R. I have created the logistic regression using the old data and evaluated that using chi^2 etc. i.e.

```
model <- glm(outcome ~ input + 0, data = training.data, family = binomial())
```

(note I do need the intercept = 0). And then the predicted probabilities:

```
predicted.probabilities <- predict(model, test.data, type = "response")
```

How can I now perform the same sort of tests with these new probabilities? and what are the best tests to do here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO, the following two tests are a good start:

1) A regression of the test outcomes on the predicted probabilities. If your predictions are correct on average ("calibrated"), the fit of this regression should be the 45° line.

2) Two separate histograms of the predicted probabilities: One for the test cases with y = 1, and one for the test cases with y = 0. If your model's predictions are sharp, the two histograms should differ a lot, with the former histogram focussing on high predicted probabilities and the latter focussing on low probabilities.

For more stuff along these lines, see Chapter 3 of

http://www.albany.edu/economics/research/workingp/2012/lahiriyang.pdf